# How to wrap .Net data provider for entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dataprovider

I will try to explain the question again:

I wanted to introduce logging in Entity Framework in such way that the query and its result along with the time the query took to execute can be logged. [Jaroslaw Kowalski](http://blogs.msdn.com/jkowalski/archive/2009/06/11/tracing-and-caching-in-entity-framework-available-on-msdn-code-gallery.aspx) has wrapped the provider to intercept communication between Entity Framework and the original provider. It also provides tracing facility which I am intending to use.

What I am confused about is the completeness of this wrapper that he has written. Currently he has only wrapping Connection, Command, Transaction, DataReader, and ProviderFactory. I am not aware of all the ways that Entity Framework communicates with the provider. I wanted to know all the ways with which Entity Framework can use data provider. For e.g. if Entity Framework uses DataAdapter or DataSets e.t.c.

Comment: You need a lot more information if you want an answer.  To be honest I don't know what the question is after reading it twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFSampleProvider) is a simple Entity Framework provider. 
Of course, in case of real DBMS different from the MS SQL Server you will meet a great number of problems, and not all of them can be solved even in theory.